# Search collection in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have table `users` and `catalogs`. Catalogs have `creator_id` which is foreign key to `id` in Users table.

Then I did this in `PostsConstructor`

```
public function index()
{
    $catalogs = Catalog::query()->get();
    $users = User::query()->get();
    return view('admin.posts',
        [
            'catalogs' => $catalogs,
            'users' => $users
        ]
    );
}
```

where I send collections to **posts.blade.php** in post blade I have:

```
@foreach( $catalogs as $catalog )

<p>Created by {{ ($users->first('id', $catalog->creator_id))->name }}</p>

@endforeach
```

**I want to show who created this post** but It shows error where my mistake is ? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the following

```
@foreach( $catalogs as $catalog )
<p>Created by {{ $users->where('id', $catalog->creator_id)->first()->name }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Yes it works Thanks.Can you explain why you put first there ?

Comment: unlike get() method which returns collection of models, first() method will return a single model instance. and you will be able to access it's property without iteration.

Comment: @bhargav kaklotara, Thank you !

Comment: @Jahid Mahmud remove "(" before $users in second line. I think there is no necessary for this braces

Comment: @BhargavKaklotara Sorry for my mistakes, I have removed the braces.